# I use direct admin and appy opcache for php 7.2 but I cannot add black list file name in opcache.ini

Tags: php, opcache

Config in opcache.ini
opcache.blacklist_filename=/opt/opcache_ignore.txt

Content in opcache_ignore.txt
`/home/cloudpro/domains/demo.cloupro.vn/public_html/config_override.cus.php`

I hope to add blacklist file name in opcache.